# ValueError at <url> Field 'id' expected a number but got ''

Tags: python, django

Estoy intentando agregar productos en un carrito de compras con django, sin embargo me aparece el siguiente error:

> ValueError at /carrito/agregar/
> Field 'id' expected a number but got ''.

En consola me indica que el error este en mi *views.py* que sería la siguiente:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponseBadRequest
from .models import Cart
from products.models import Product

def add_to_cart(request, product_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            # Obtener el producto a partir de su ID
            product = Product.objects.get(pk=product_id)
            
            # Obtener el carrito del usuario
            cart = Cart.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
            
            # Agregar el producto al carrito
            cart.products.add(product)
            
            # Redireccionar a la página del carrito
            return redirect('cart')  # Ajusta el nombre de la vista de acuerdo a tu configuración
            
        except Product.DoesNotExist:
            return HttpResponseBadRequest("El producto no existe.")
    
    return HttpResponseBadRequest("Método de solicitud no válido.")
```

Comment: ¿Y estás pasando el id en la petición?

Comment: Si, pero aun asi sigue apareciendo el error.

Comment: La PK de tu modelo producto es un entero?

Comment: La pk es product_id, según mi profesor con eso debería funcionar.